# Getting EPSG code in pyproj with version==2.1.3?

Tags: python, epsg, pyproj

I'm using `pyproj` in python and I want to get epsg code based on an existing `Proj` class. An example in version=1.9.6:

```
from pyproj import Proj
CGCS2000metre = Proj(init='EPSG:4544')
print(CGCS2000metre.srs)

# +units=m +init=epsg:4544
```

As you can see, I can find epsg code `4544` in the return result. But I can't do it in version==2.1.3:

```
from pyproj import Proj
CGCS2000metre = Proj(init='EPSG:4544')
print(CGCS2000metre.srs)

# +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=105 +k=1 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
```

I just want to get epsg code from an existing `Proj`.

How can I get epsg code in pyproj with version==2.1.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [pyproj.CRS](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/crs.html#pyproj-crs)

```python
from pyproj import CRS
CGCS2000metre = CRS('epsg:4544')
print(CGCS2000metre.to_epsg()) # prints "4544"
```

To get a CRS in the way you're already using pyproj, you can get a CRS object like this:

```python
from pyproj import Proj
CGCS2000metre = Proj(init='EPSG:4544').crs
print(CGCS2000metre.to_epsg()) # prints None
print(CGCS2000metre.to_epsg(min_confidence=25) # prints "4544"
```

https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/proj.html#pyproj.proj.Proj.crs

Your misunderstanding is that [`srs`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/proj.html#pyproj.proj.Proj.srs) is "the string form of the user input used to create the Proj".

You might need to adjust the `min_confidence`. There's a Q&A to understand that parameter here: [Explaining pyproj to_epsg min_confidence parameter?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326690/explnation-of-the-pyproj-to-epsg-min-confidence-parameter)

Comment: I get `None` when I use `from pyproj import Proj
CGCS2000metre = Proj(init='EPSG:4544').crs
print(CGCS2000metre.to_epsg())`.

Comment: It's strange that I get `4544` when I use `from pyproj import CRS
CGCS2000metre = CRS('epsg:4544')
print(CGCS2000metre.to_epsg())`. But I can't get epsg code based on an existing `Proj` in this way.

Comment: Try to adjust the `min_confidence` param. (I've edited the question.)

Comment: It works. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand the `min_confidence` parameter here, so I made another question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326690/explnation-of-the-pyproj-to-epsg-min-confidence-parameter I hope that's OK.

Comment: Haha, I expect someone to answer the question.