# Explaining pyproj to_epsg min_confidence parameter?

Tags: python, proj, python-3, pyproj

Following on from this question [How can I get epsg code in pyproj with version==2.1.3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326687/how-can-i-get-epsg-code-in-pyproj-with-version-2-1-3/326688?noredirect=1#comment532386_326688), I discovered that sometimes when intialising a pyproj `Proj` instance with a string ESPG code eventually results in an ambiguity when trying to determine the projection's EPSG code.

```python
from pyproj import Proj
crs = Proj(init='epsg:4544').crs
print(crs.to_epsg())
# prints None
```

If you adjust the`min_confidence` parameter, then you can get it out:

```python
from pyproj import Proj
crs = Proj(init='epsg:4544').crs
print(crs.to_epsg(min_confidence=25) # <-- !!
# prints 4544
```

I feel like this is something I should understand, but I don't. **What is the ambiguity here; why does the `to_epsg` method require this `min_confidence` parameter to return a valid EPSG code in this case?**

Reading the [source code](https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/blob/4ce78dd8f4c8324b60c43bb321f71ac719d47cd4/pyproj/_crs.pyx#L1534) is not enlightening regarding the source of the ambiguity:

```
Parameters
----------
min_confidence: int, optional
  A value between 0-100 where 100 is the most confident. Default is 70.

Returns
-------
int or None: The best matching EPSG code matching the confidence level.
```

Reading that function, as well as `to_authority`, I surmise that the ambiguity arises when there are multiple matches, and the confidence score allows pyproj to return the best candidate. I don't particularly understand that either, but it does make sense. What really doesn't make sense is how `None` can be a better candidate than `4544` in this case, especially when the `Proj` instance was initialised without an exception or warning.

Notably, using a `CRS` instance instead, but with the same EPSG string input, seems to be unambiguous:

```python
from pyproj import CRS
crs = CRS('epsg:4544')
print(crs.to_epsg())
# prints "4544"
```

```python
>>> import pyproj
>>> pyproj.__version__
'2.2.0'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a great question and I will do my best to answer.

To begin, the `init` style syntax is deprecated (https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#init-auth-auth-code-should-be-replaced-with-auth-auth-code). So, instead of `CRS(init="epsg:4544")`, you should use `CRS("epsg:4544")`.

> I discovered that sometimes when intialising a pyproj Proj instance with a string ESPG code eventually results in an ambiguity when trying to determine the projection's EPSG code.

The reason that the EPSG code does not appear with the CRS initialized with the `init=` syntax is that the CRS are different.

```py
>>> from pyproj import CRS
>>> crs_deprecated = CRS(init="epsg:4544")
>>> crs = CRS("epsg:4544")
>>> crs == crs_deprecated
False
```

Upon further inspection, you can see that the difference is in the axis order (although it is not immediately apparent to the eye due to the content being the same).

```py
>>> crs_deprecated
<Projected CRS: +init=epsg:4544 +type=crs>
Name: CGCS2000 / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger CM 105E
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- E[east]: Easting (metre)
- N[north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: China - 103.5°E to 106.5°E
- bounds: (103.5, 22.5, 106.5, 42.21)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: Gauss-Kruger CM 105E
- method: Transverse Mercator
Datum: China 2000
- Ellipsoid: CGCS2000
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich

>>> crs
<Projected CRS: EPSG:4544>
Name: CGCS2000 / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger CM 105E
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- X[north]: Northing (metre)
- Y[east]: Easting (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: China - 103.5°E to 106.5°E
- bounds: (103.5, 22.5, 106.5, 42.21)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: Gauss-Kruger CM 105E
- method: Transverse Mercator
Datum: China 2000
- Ellipsoid: CGCS2000
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

> why does the to_epsg method require this min_confidence parameter to return a valid EPSG code in this case?

The reason the `min_confidence` parameter exists is because of the example above. If you have a WKT/PROJ string and you use it to create the CRS instance, in most cases you want to be sure that the EPSG code given by `to_epsg` will give you a `CRS` instance similar to the one created by the WKT/PROJ string. However, if an EPSG code does not exist that matches you WKT/PROJ string with a `min_confidence` you don't want to get that EPSG code back as it will make you think that the WKT/PROJ string and the EPSG code are one and the same when they are not.

However, if you are only wanting to get the EPSG code that is closest to the PROJ/WKT string, then you can reduce your `min_confidence` to a threshold you are comfortable with.

Here is an example of that:

```py
>>> crs_deprecated = CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
>>> crs_deprecated.to_epsg(100)
>>> crs_deprecated.to_epsg(70)
>>> crs_deprecated.to_epsg(20)
4326
>>> crs_latlon = CRS("+proj=latlon")
>>> crs_latlon.to_epsg(100)
>>> crs_latlon.to_epsg(70)
4326
>>> crs_epsg = CRS.from_epsg(4326)
>>> crs_epsg.to_epsg(100)
4326
>>> crs_wkt = CRS(crs_epsg.to_wkt())
>>> crs_wkt.to_epsg(100)
4326
>>> crs_wkt == crs_epsg
True
>>> crs_epsg == crs_latlon
False
>>> crs_epsg == crs_deprecated
False
```

Hopefully this helps resolve some of the confusion.

For reference of the `pyproj` related versions I used in this example:

```
$ python -c "import pyproj; pyproj.show_versions()"

System:
    python: 3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 27 2019, 23:01:00)  [GCC 7.3.0]
executable: ~/miniconda3/envs/pyproj/bin/python
   machine: Linux-4.15.0-51-generic-x86_64-with-debian-buster-sid

PROJ:
      PROJ: 6.1.1
  data dir: ~/scripts/pyproj/pyproj/proj_dir/share/proj

Python deps:
    pyproj: 2.2.1
       pip: 18.0
setuptools: 41.0.1
    Cython: 0.29.10
     aenum: (2, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a really good answer. I understood that `CRS` without `init` was favoured now, and I intend to use it. I think my misunderstanding probably begins with proj strings in general: I've never really used them beyond declaring simple, popular EPSG codes; maybe occasionally setting a new origin latitude; maybe once or twice attempting a polar projection. Is there a better way to declare a proj string that reduces ambiguity?

Comment: The best format for your projection is in the format it originated in. For example, if you have a WKT string or an EPSG code, you want to keep it in the original format. If you convert to a PROJ string from a WKT or EPSG code, you will likely lose information. See: https://proj.org/faq.html#what-is-the-best-format-for-describing-coordinate-reference-systems.

Comment: I think I'm still unclear how/why `CRS("+proj=epsg:xxxx")` contains less information than a bare `CRS.from_epsg(xxxx)`.

Comment: It is not necessarily less in that case. The init version is deprecated and produces a different CRS with a different axis order.

Comment: OK. So why is it unable to return the EPSG code with high confidence, given that is literally the only piece of information it has been given? I figure there's something fundamental I'm missing here.

Comment: It is because the axis order is different than the one created with the non-deprecated version.

Comment: OK, so the two are similar, but not equivalent, hence the low confidence (but it ultimately reveals the association). There's also a historical mess with GIS vendors ignoring the ISO standard for axis order. I understand the result as far as a strict equality check may be concerned, but it's certainly surprising behavior when just attempting to get the numeric EPSG code back out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `The reason that the EPSG code does not appear with the CRS initialized with the init= syntax is that the CRS are different.`  don't you mean the result is different?  I mean 4544 is just a reference to a definition of a CRS in the EPSG database,  the EPSG database has always defined axis order for its CRS/datums etc it's just that some software in the past has not referred to the axis order or incorrectly stated it.  So init="epsg:4544" does a lookup with incorrect axis order, and pyProj.CRS  is axis aware.

Comment: Essentially, yes. The init= syntax is deprecated and is there only for backwards compatibility with previous versions of PROJ with respect to axis order.

Comment: I get all what was said above. However, only if I use the depreciated syntax ( `from_proj="+init=epsg:4326"` - `to_proj="+init=epsg:32643"`) am I getting correctly projected geometries (`tf = Transformer.from_crs(from_proj, to_proj)` and then `tf.transform(lng, lat)`. If I use the non-depreciated "epsg:32643", my projected geometries have flipped (wrong) axis.

Comment: Well, found out what was biting me: I had to use `Transformer.from_crs(from_proj, to_proj, always_xy=True)`. Apparently, there was a [discussion](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1036) to make this the default, but it is not clear where this ended. This should be added to the [gotchas](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/dev/gotchas.html) section of pyproj docs..