# Matplotlib Basemap how to set EPSG to be consistent with new version of pyrpoj

Tags: python, pyproj, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-basemap

I am getting a Matplotlib Basemap error related to pyproj and setting the EPSG. (I know Basemap is being depreciated, but this is what I am working in for now.) As a result, I can't plot the `arcgisimage` basemap.

I'm working in a new env, so I think it is related to a pyproj update (everything worked perfectly in the old environment). I think I need to change how the EPSG is set in `m = Basemap()` in my code below, but I can't find the correct syntax in my searches.

**Error:**

```
C:\myenvpath\lib\site-packages\pyproj\crs\crs.py:53: FutureWarning: '+init=<authority>:<code>' syntax is deprecated. '<authority>:<code>' is the preferred initialization method. When making the change, be mindful of axis order changes: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#axis-order-changes-in-proj-6
  return _prepare_from_string(" ".join(pjargs))
C:\myenvpath\lib\site-packages\pyproj\crs\crs.py:294: FutureWarning: '+init=<authority>:<code>' syntax is deprecated. '<authority>:<code>' is the preferred initialization method. When making the change, be mindful of axis order changes: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#axis-order-changes-in-proj-6
  projstring = _prepare_from_string(" ".join((projstring, projkwargs)))
```

**Code:**

```
south, north = 34.2, 34.5
west, east = -118.3, -118.0
center = [(east + west) / 2, (north + south) / 2]
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon = west, llcrnrlat = south, urcrnrlon = east, urcrnrlat = north,
                resolution = 'c', epsg = 4326, lon_0 = center[0], lat_0 = center[1], 
                suppress_ticks = False)
img = m.arcgisimage(service = "World_Shaded_Relief", xpixels = 2000)
img.set_alpha(0.5)
```

[image]

Using Jupyter Notebook & running the following:
Windows 10
conda 4.8.2
Python 3.8.3
basemap 1.3.0 py38hcdd3ad8_2 conda-forge
matplotlib 3.2.1 0 conda-forge
matplotlib-base 3.2.1 py38h1626042_0 conda-forge
pyproj 2.6.1.post1 py38h1dd9442_0 conda-forge

Comment: That is a warning, not an error. So, I don't think that is not the reason it isn't working.

Comment: If the warning is raised, it means it is using `+init=` syntax. That means the axis ordering is the same as if you were using `always_xy=True`.

Comment: See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/326919/1443579

Comment: thanks for the explanations. I think Basemap is using `+init=` under the hood, and I don't know how to work around it. I tried various things like `Basemap(etc..., epsg=CRS.from_epsg(4326))` but of course it didn't work.

Comment: It is fine if it uses `init=` under the hood. No problems there.