# "init" CRS vs regular CRS in GeoPandas

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, epsg

I have a shapefile which I read in via

```
import geopandas as gpd
shapes_df = gpd.read_file(shp_f)
print(shapes_df.crs)
```

The output was `{'init': 'epsg:3857'}`

I then reprojected via

```
shapes_df = shapes_df.to_crs("epsg:32629")
print(shapes_df.crs)
```

The output was `epsg:32629`

What is the meaning of the 'init' value for the CRS in the original CRS? Should I be concerned that there is no 'init' value in my reprojected data? Did the projection not work properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the meaning of the 'init' value for the CRS in the original CRS?

It is for PROJ string initialization. That format is deprecated for CRS strings, so it is better to not have it (https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#init-auth-auth-code-should-be-replaced-with-auth-auth-code).

Reference for axis order:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/326919/144357

> Should I be concerned that there is no 'init' value in my reprojected data?

Depends if the axis order is important to you.

> Did the projection not work properly?

That depends on the version of geopandas and pyproj. If you have geopandas 6+, then you should be fine.